# Qn on the book Learn Prolog Now

Tags: prolog, predicate

The part of the book I'm referring to is here,
http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node4.html

```
listensToMusic(mia).
happy(yolanda).
playsAirGuitar(mia)  :- listensToMusic(mia).
playsAirGuitar(yolanda) :- listensToMusic(yolanda).
listensToMusic(yolanda):- happy(yolanda).
```

> The `happy` predicate is defined using a single clause (a fact). The
>   `listensToMusic` and `playsAirGuitar` predicates are each defined
>   using two clauses (in both cases, two rules).

I understand the first part where it says that the `happy` predicate is defined using a single clause (a fact). But I don't understand the next part where it says  `listensToMusic`
and `playsAirGuitar` predicates are each defined using two clauses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the book is a little inconsistent or confusing in what clauses are *facts* and *rules*:

> The facts and rules contained in a knowledge base are called clauses.
>   Thus KB2 contains five clauses, **namely three rules and two facts.**
>   Another way of looking at KB2 is to say that it consists of three
>   predicates (or procedures). The three predicates are:
>
> ```
> listensToMusic
> happy
> playsAirGuitar
> ```
>
> The happy predicate is defined using a single clause (**a fact**). The
>   listensToMusic and playsAirGuitar predicates are each defined using
>   two clauses (in both cases, **two rules**).

I think the parenthesis "*(in both cases, two rules)*" is just adding confusion - `listensToMusic(mia).` is an empty rule, i.e. a fact.

The text could be trying to establish a difference between when looking at a Prolog knowledge base as a whole (a set of clauses) and as a set of predicates - seen as a predicate, `happy` has only fact clauses while `listensToMusic` has both fact and rule clauses.

If you get that `listensToMusic/1` is defined with two clauses (one empty rule, one non-empty):

```
listensToMusic(mia).
listensToMusic(yolanda):- happy(yolanda).
```

...and `playsAirGuitar/1` is defined with two clauses (two non-empty rules):

```
playsAirGuitar(mia)  :- listensToMusic(mia).
playsAirGuitar(yolanda) :- listensToMusic(yolanda).
```

...I think you will be fine. Don't worry!